# Converting SID in HES to SDDL format

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, sid

I am doing an LDAP query to get the distinguished name of a User.  The DN section contains the Guid and SID but the SID section is HEX.

How can I convert this SID in HES format to SDDL format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can use [SecurityIdentifier class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.securityidentifier.aspx).

Comment: How so ?  I am getting sid in the form of this "<SID=010500000000000515000000a0607e5afa7af7a99aea8aaa4ea40000>" and I want to convert to sddl , I couldn't find how to do this in SecurityIdentifier class.

Comment: How do you get This ?
SecurityIdentifier  has a constructor with a byte array, and you can transform what you have into a byte array.

Comment: Thanks , I convert this to byte array (every 2 char is a hex) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [JPBlanc's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6620161/2594742)...

You can create a small helper function for this, like so:

```
private static String ResolveSID(Byte[] sidBytes)
{
    return (new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(sidBytes, 0).ToString());
}
```